# How to Redirect to controller Form Shared Layout View using Nav menu

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, nav

I am working in Asp.net MVC 5. In shared layout,i am using **nav** to redirect to Index View of Controller but its not working. showing error **Resources cannot found**
Following is the code of NAV

```
<ul class="sidebar navbar-nav">
<li class="nav-item active">
<a class="nav-link" href="~/Controllers/ContractorsController.cs/Index.cshtml">
<i class="fas fa-fw fa-chart-area"></i>
<span>Contractors</span>
```

In these Controllers [image] i want to redirect to ContractorsControllers

And to Index View of Contractors Controller.

Comment: `href="/Contractors/Index"` (or better, use `href="@Url.Action("Index", "Contractors")"`

Comment: Just use `<a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Contractors")">`. No need to use `.cs` and `.cshtml` extension because MVC route based from routes.

Comment: Note that in MVC, you do not navigate to a view file - you navigate to a controller method which returns a view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank u sir, It works For me..

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Got that Thank you for solving my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MVC you cannot directly navigate to View. Use below code.

```
<a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Contractors")">
```